# Flex column align-items: flex-start not working

Tags: html, css, flexbox

In the flex column layout, the align-items works with every value except flex-start. On the image, this right boxes should touch to the image, not having space between. Making the right divs width:100% could solve the problem, but then they get really 100% of the container which makes them stand out of the container :/

[image]

The code:

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 300px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-start;
  outline: solid 1px green;
}

.flex-item {
  background: blue;
  color: white;
  outline: red solid 1px;
}

.flex-item:first-of-type {
  height: 100%;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
  <div class="flex-item">first block</div>
  <div class="flex-item">description</div>
  <div class="flex-item">123,00€</div>
</div>
```

Comment: align-content instead of align-items

Comment: Omg such a stupid problem, I've read somewhere align-content is only for grid layout hence I haven't even tested it. Thanks, of course this is the exact solution.